# Documenting TypeScript transpiled API with Swagger

Tags: typescript, swagger, swagger-ui

I installed `swagger-jsdoc` and `swagger-ui-express`. Then I created the options file for the UI and wrote the relative address of the `apis`. Then where I initialize my API service I call the options and put them in `specs` to insert it in the `swaggerUi.setup`. The user view is created correctly, but I don't see the endpoints in the UI.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OPmG.png)

Options file:

```
export const options = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
      openapi: '3.0.0',
      info: {
        title: 'MEnvio API',
        version: '1.0.0',
        description: 'Doumentación de los enpoints de la API del Backend del sistema MIEnvio',
      },
      servers: [
        {
          url: 'http://localhost:1802',
        },
      ],
    },
    apis: ['./routes/*.js'],

      };
```

Server app:

```
import express, { Application, json, urlencoded } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import usersRoute from './routes/usersRoute';
import viajeRoute from './routes/viajeRoute';
import swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';
import swaggerJsDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';
import { options } from './swaggerOptios';
class Server {
  private backend: Application;
  private userRouter: usersRoute;
  private viajeRoute: viajeRoute
  constructor() {
    dotenv.config();
    this.backend = express();
    this.userRouter = new usersRoute();
    this.viajeRoute = new viajeRoute();
    this.config();
    this.route();
    this.start();

  }
  public config = () => {
    this.backend.set('port', process.env.PORT);
    this.backend.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.backend.use(json());
    this.backend.use(cors());
    const specs = swaggerJsDoc(options);
    console.log(specs);
    this.backend.use('/docs',swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(specs));

  }
  public route = () => {
    this.backend.use(`${process.env.USERSROUTE}`, this.userRouter.router);
    this.backend.use(`${process.env.USERSROUTE}`, this.viajeRoute.router);
  }
  public start = () => {
    this.backend.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log('Server on port:', process.env.PORT);
    });
  }
}
const server = new Server();
```

Endpoints file:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import userController from '../controller/usersController';
class usersRoute {
  public router: Router;
  public controller: userController;
  constructor() {
    this.router = Router();
    this.controller = new userController();
    this.config();
  }
  public config() {
    this.router.post('/login', this.controller.login);
    this.router.post('/register', this.controller.register);
    /**
    * @swagger
    * /getDataUser:
    *  get:
    *    summary: Returns a list of tasks
    */
    this.router.get('/getDataUser/:id', this.controller.getUserData);
    this.router.post('/updateUser', this.controller.updateUser);
  }
}
export default usersRoute;
```

I am transpiling to JS in the dist folder:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eYmK.png)

I thought the endpoint could be seen in the Swagger UI, but you can't see it.